# Parameters on Nested Facebook API Request?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make a call to Facebook using their Graph API Explorer, to try and find the following information about an ad:

1. Its adset,
2. Its branded page (if any),
3. Insights about its 100% video views.

To do that, I have constructed the following URL:

```
act_1234/ads?fields=id,adcreatives{branded_content_sponsor_page_id},insights{video_p100_watched_actions}&limit=1000
```

However, when I receive back the insights list, it is giving me just one row, for the last month.  If I was making a call directly to insights, I would add the 'timeincrement=1' parameter to separate this out by day.  Is there a way to add second-tier parameters to a nested query like this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can pass parameters to nested queries this way:

```
act_1234/ads?fields=id,adcreatives{branded_content_sponsor_page_id},insights.fields(video_p100_watched_actions).date_preset(lifetime).time_increment(1)
```

Comment: Very nice -- I'd tried to use .timeincrement(1) before, but hadn't realized I needed to use .fields() to enable that.